# wicket select propertymode- -no get method defined

Tags: data-binding, wicket

I am making a simple dropdown component in wicket, following the example here:http://www.mkyong.com/wicket/wicket-select-example/

now I get the error: 
Last cause: No get method defined for class: class no.polaris.AdressaHomePage expression: 2011

Anybody see what is wrong? (it doesn`t help with a getter for selectedYear).

Cheers
Terje Eithun

```
public class AdressaHomePage extends BasePage {

private String selectedYear = "2011";

public AdressaHomePage(final PageParameters parameters) {

    add(new FeedbackPanel("feedback"));

    Form<?> form = new Form<Void>("form") {

        @Override
        protected void onSubmit() {
            info("Selected year: " + selectedYear);
        }
    };
    add(form);  

    Select<String> yearSelector = new Select<String>("year-selector", new PropertyModel<String>(this, selectedYear));

    yearSelector.add(new SelectOption<String>("year1", new Model<String>("2012")));
    yearSelector.add(new SelectOption<String>("year2", new Model<String>("2011")));
    yearSelector.add(new SelectOption<String>("year3", new Model<String>("2010")));
    yearSelector.add(new SelectOption<String>("year4", new Model<String>("2009")));
    form.add(yearSelector);
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

new PropertyModel(this,"selectedYear")

Note the quotation marks.